# psql : load query from file and output psql messages to log file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, psql

I'm trying to find a one-liner to read query from external file and output psql NOTICEs to a log file.
I tried :

```
psql -h host -d database -U username -f my_sql_file.sql > my_log_file.log
```

my_sql_file.sql has a multiline anonymous block like :

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  stuff 
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '--------- TEST ----------';
END;
$$
```

The log file outputs the first line of the file : "DO" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice gets written to standard error, so redirect that too:

```sh
psql -h host -d database -U username -f my_sql_file.sql > my_log_file.log 2>&1
```